# Uploading Webcam-easy.js snap to a node.js server

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to upload a photo from the web page to a node.js web server behind, I just cannot figure out how to upload the picture that Webcam-easy.js has generated by doing `let picture = webcam.snap();`, it also saves it to a canvas. It needs to be a POST request. The URL it need's to be uploaded to is /upload/ and the image needs to be tagged as file. When the backend gets it it saves the file to an uploads folder.